# how to provide authorization in Spring. Cloud Gateway which is done by KeyCloak

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Spring Cloud Gateway and to provide authentication and authorization in my application I am using Keycloak.  I have an endpoint which needs to be secured from Keycloak as only the users who has specific role is able to use that endpoint. I created a Role called "A" and assigned that A role to user B. IT works perfect but I do not know how to authorize "customer/api/v2/customers" post endpoint for only role A? Do you know a way to do it ?

Maybe this question is not fully related with Keycloak. But I want to find out if there is a way to do it or if you have accomplished such kind of issue before ?

Thank you

My Sample Code:

```
- id: create user 
uri: https://createcustomertest:8543 
predicates: 
- Path=/customer/api/v2/customers/** 
- Method=POST 
filters: 
- StripPrefix=1
```

Comment: Can you rephrase "how to say that only the rest endpoints who is directed to that link that have A role can accesss this endpoint"? I don't seem to understand it...

Comment: hello k.waselliweskk. I updated the question

Comment: And what is this code you've posted exactly? Can you share your SecuriyConfig?

Comment: The code I posted is the configmap.yaml configurations of Kubernetes for this service